# Updating <video> src with checkbox and button

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I believe I'm having a relatively simple problem with a video player implementation in javascript. To start, I want to add a string to an array and reference that first string entry as the src of my source in my video tag. I then want the video to begin playing once the src is received.

I have not implemented the code for the latter since I haven't gotten past the former yet. I've seen people make reference to a .load() function call after changing the src but I don't know if I'm correctly setting the src to begin with.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

video
{
    background-color:#333;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var width = (1280 * 0.1);
var height = (720 * 0.1);
var resized = false;

function getWidth(){
    return width;
}

function getHeight(){
    return height;
}


//Create array. Checkbox adds video to list.
//"Submit" button gives first video in list to player.

var videoList = new Array();
var i = 0; //incrementer

//Use checkbox's value as argument
function addVideo(value){
    videoList[i] = value;
    i++;
}

function videoSubmit(){
    document.getElementById("player").setAttribute("src", videoList[i]);
}

</script>

<video id="test" width="getWidth()" height="getHeight()">
<source id="player" src="null" type="video/avi" width="getWidth()"     height="getHeight()"/>

</video>
<br/>

<form id="selector" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="firstvideo" value="test.avi" onClick="addVideo(test.avi)"/> sample 1.avi<br/>

</form>

<button onClick="videoSubmit()"> Submit</button>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm quite new to javascript and am still trying to wrap my head around it. Any helpful information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `i` has the wrong value.  Try:

```
function videoSubmit(){
    document.getElementById("player").setAttribute("src", videoList[ i - 1 ]);
}
```

There are a few other issues as well.  Here's a fixed version - enjoy:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrSYC/

Another problem:

You can't do this:

```
<video id="test" width="getWidth()" height="getHeight()">
```

If you want to programatically set those attributes, you must do it the same way you are with the src attribute.  Sometimes you'll see this sort of construct, but it's clumsy:

```
<script>document.write('<video id="test" width="' + getWidth() + '" ...')</script>
```

Unrelated to the Q - you could skip a lot of javascript learning pain by jumping straight to jquery.  It does incur a page-load penalty, but it cures a lot of the annoyances of pure javascript.  Doing it the old fashioned way will give you "valuable experience" - which those of us who have it value probably more than warranted.

http://jquery.com/

Comment: The change did not help, but thank you for the reference to jquery. Will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra `source` element here and can simply target the `src` attribute of the `video` element.

So something like:

```
document.getElementById('test').src = videoList[i];
```

should be all you need to do (assuming that the value of `videoList[i]` is a valid URL to the video file and that the browser in question can play it).